# How to delete from multiple tables with the same column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with the below structure where there is no relation of (PK / FK).

```
======== country =======
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | visible |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | kkk   |       0 |
|  2 | mmm   |       1 |
|  3 | ttt   |       1 |
|  4 | kkkkk |       0 |
+----+-------+---------+

============ city =============
+----+------+---------+-------+
| id | name | visible | c_id  |
+----+------+---------+-------+
|  3 | k333 |       0 |     1 |
|  2 | k222 |       1 |     1 |
|  1 | kkk  |       1 |     1 |
|  4 | k444 |       0 |     2 |
|  6 | k666 |       0 |     2 |
+----+------+---------+-------+
```

I am using country.id and city.country_id as the link between the 2 tables. I am trying to delete the countries and cities where visibility value is 0. After searching I came up with this piece of code:

```
delete country , city from country, city where city.country_id = country.id and country.id in (select id from country where visible = 0);
```

But it returns the below error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'country' for update in FROM clause
```

I tried to use JOIN with WHERE like this :

```
DELETE country , city 
FROM country JOIN city 
ON city.country_id = country.id 
WHERE  country.visible = 0
```

It worked well, but there is one more row which is having the value of 0 was not deleted.

```
======== Country ======
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | visible |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 | mmm   |       1 |
|  3 | ttt   |       1 |
|  4 | kkkkk |       0 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JOIN with a WHERE, it is much clearer.

```
DELETE country , city 
FROM country JOIN city 
ON city.country_id = country.id 
WHERE  country.visible = 0
```

ON your sample data the kkk row with visible=0 wont be deleted since it has an id of 4 which doenst exist in the city table so it won`t be picked up in the join.

Comment: It worked, but still for country there is one more value which is having value 0, please see the result below :

+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | visible |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 | mmm   |       1 |
|  3 | ttt         |       1 |
|  4 | kkkkk   |       0 |
+----+-------+---------+

Comment: @Kamal Not clear,but I`m guessing you need a LEFT join.

Comment: With the LEFT JOIN all data from county table was deleted.

Comment: @Kamal The only reason I can think of the first query didnt work is that the country didnt have a join id to the city table.

Answer (score 2):

@Mihai After I checked your code again I just added WHERE and it worked like this:

```
DELETE country, city 
FROM country 
LEFT JOIN city 
ON city.country_id = country.id 
WHERE country.visible = 0;
```